# How can I simply add a downloadable PDF file to my page?

Tags: ms-word

I want to add a pdf and word format of my resume to my portfolio page and make it downloadable. Does anyone have some simple script?

Comment: Are you using a server-side scripting language, or must it be client-side?

Comment: Are you talking about adding it to your user profile page or your careers profile page?

Comment: What programming question is being asked? If this isn't a programming question (as it appears), then `superuser.com` seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Add a link to the file and let the browser handle the download.

You may be over-complicating the problem. It's possible to use a `href` pointing to the location of the `.pdf` or `.doc` file, when a user clicks on this in their browser, generally they will be asked if they would like to save or open the file, depending on their OS/configuration.

If this is still confusing, leave a comment and I'll explain anything you don't get.

Answer (score 1):

Create the PDF. Upload it. Add a link.

Save yourself 30 minutes tossing around with PDFGEN code.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to issue or employ the [**Content-Disposition** HTTP header](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) to **force the download** otherwise some browsers may recognize the common file extensions and try to automatically open the file contents. **It will feel more professional** if the link actually downloads the file instead of launching an app - important for a resume I think.

Content-Disposition must be generated within the page from the server side as far as I know.

Comment: Unfortunately, "professional" may mean "using IE6" in some industries. IE6 content-disposition support appears very flaky (from the link you provided).

Comment: It's more of a catch-all than not including it. A special footnote can always be mentioned if IE6 is detected by the page.

Comment: Heh, I thought of an alternative way to view the problem: we're programmers, if someone's using IE6 to view our CV, we didn't want the job anyway :-p

Comment: I usually use Safari. Safari opens PDF files seamlessly as if they were just another web page. It's always jarring to click on a PDF and have it download to a file somewhere on my disk, instead of simply displaying in a browser window (where I can "Save As" if I want to keep a copy).

Answer (score 0):

Option:

- Upload your resume to [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/).
- Add a link to the file on your portfolio page just as I do in the menu of my [blog](http://www.leniel.net/):
- Use [Google Docs Viewer](https://drive.googleblog.com/2009/09/view-online-files-using-google-docs.html) passing to it the URL of the PDF as you can see in this [link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fleniel.googlepages.com%2FLenielMacaferiResumeEnglish.pdf).